# How to avoid public int field from JAXB serialization?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How can I avoid field from being serialized? I use xml attributes. Currently field has no attribute but gets to xml...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Annotate the field you want to exclude with `@XmlTransient`.

Answer (score 4):

**Option #1 - Change the Accessor Type**

By default a [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation will treat all public fields and properties as being mapped.  If you want to restrict this to just public properties then you can do the following:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Foo {

    public int bar; // Not considered mapped if access type is set to PROPERTY

}
```

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

---

**Option #2 - Specify the Field is Unmapped**

You can mark a field/property with `@XmlTransient` to prevent it from being mapped.

```
public class Foo {

    @XmlTransient
    public int bar; // Not considered mapped

}
```

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html